# Interaction plot - coding fail for Two-way anova in R

Tags: r, transformation, interaction, anova, sqrt

I am trying to analyse and present the results of Gastropod abundance vs. height on the shore and species in a Two-Way ANOVA.

This is the dataset   http://dropcanvas.com/ercb6

The data has been sqrt transformed and an ANOVA test was successful. In my sample code below I was able to make an interaction plot of the normal Gastropod data. However, I want to make an interaction plot using the transformed data but I do not know how to alter the code to allow this. Suggestions?

```
Gastropods = read.csv(file = "MaroubraZones.csv", header = TRUE)
boxplot(Abundance ~ Zone*Species,data = Gastropods, names = c("A.high", "A.mid", "A.low", "C.high", "C.mid", "C.low", "N.high", "N.mid", "N.low"))
Gastropods.ANOVA = aov(Abundance ~ Zone * Species, data = Gastropods)
hist(Gastropods.ANOVA$residuals)
plot(Gastropods.ANOVA)
summary(Gastropods.ANOVA)
Gastropods$sqrtAbundance = sqrt(Gastropods$Abundance +1)
Gastropods.aov = aov(Gastropods$sqrtAbundance ~ Zone + Species + Zone:Species, data = Gastropods)
summary(Gastropods.aov)

interaction.plot(Gastropods$Zone, Gastropods$Species, Gastropods$Abundance, main= "Gastropod Interaction Plot", xlab = "Gastropod Zone", ylab= "Mean of Gastropod Abundance", legend = TRUE)
```

Comment: This does not work?    `interaction.plot(Gastropods$Zone, Gastropods$Species, Gastropods$sqrtAbundance, main= "Gastropod Interaction Plot", xlab = "Gastropod Zone", ylab= "Mean of SQRT Gastropod Abundance", legend = TRUE)`

Comment: *facepalm* Wow. I swear I tried that and got an error...Thank you so much for helping with my extreme noobness. Also, I was wondering if you could help explain how to label error bars on a barplot? I've searched everywhere and not come up with anything. I'm a total beginner to this. A link to a relevant source even would be fantastic. Thank you again.

Comment: Use yaxt or xaxt ="n" inside a plot or barplot. Whit axis() you could label the axis as you want. For introdutory material maybe this: http://www.introductoryr.co.uk/R_Resources_for_Beginners.html.

Comment: I've only been here a day or two but the community has been awesome. Thanks for the help and the link. I'm officially allowed up vote so i have done that for you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the question:

```
interaction.plot(Gastropods$Zone, Gastropods$Species, Gastropods$sqrtAbundance, main= "Gastropod Interaction Plot", xlab = "Gastropod Zone", ylab= "Mean of SQRT Gastropod Abundance", legend = TRUE)
```